# Kotlin Location is far from my location How can i make it more accurity

Tags: android, kotlin, location

```
private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val name=findViewById(R.id.editText) as TextView
        var text=""
        locationManager = getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager?

        val button =findViewById(R.id.button) as Button
        var mainlink=""
        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)   == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            val adresstext= findViewById(R.id.editText3)as TextView
            var deneme=""
            fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
            fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener {

            }
            fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener {
                    location -> location

                var locationx=location.longitude
                var locationy=location.latitude

                val name = findViewById(R.id.textView) as TextView
                var geocoder: Geocoder
                var listadress :List<Address>


                geocoder = Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
                listadress =geocoder.getFromLocation(locationy,locationx,1)
                var adress=listadress[0].getAddressLine(0)
                adresstext.text=adress
                text=deneme
                mainlink="http://maps.google.com/maps?q="+locationy+","+locationx+""
                mainlink=mainlink+" "+text
                text=mainlink
            }
        }
        else
        {
            val permission= arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permission,0)
        }
```

Everything is OK, but when it takes location it takes 200m far from me. How can I make it more accurate?
I take the longitude and latitude for my device it takes it but when i show in google map it gives the location 200 m away I checked the longitude latitude and google maps.
And the failure on latitude and longitude it takes far from me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls try this!

```
private fun requestLocationUpdates() {
        var mLocationRequest = LocationRequest()
        mLocationRequest!!.setInterval(AppConstants.LOCATION_INTERVAL.toLong())
        mLocationRequest!!.setFastestInterval(AppConstants.FASTEST_LOCATION_INTERVAL.toLong())
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
        var client: FusedLocationProviderClient =
            LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(applicationContext)

        val permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            applicationContext,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        )
        if (permission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Request location updates and when an update is
            client.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, object : LocationCallback() {
                override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult?) {
                    val location = locationResult!!.lastLocation
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location!!.latitude
                        longitude = location!!.longitude

                        AppConstants.CURRENT_LATITUDE = location!!.latitude
                        AppConstants.CURRENT_LONGITUDE = location!!.longitude

                    }
                }
            }, null)
        }
    }

class AppConstants {
 var CURRENT_LATITUDE = 0.0
 var CURRENT_LONGITUDE = 0.0
}
```

Comment: iss AppConstant a library becouse my android studio couldnt define it

Comment: @OğuzKurukaya AppConstant  is just a constant class which i've used globally.

Comment: so i cant use the code without it ? how can i create it

Comment: @OğuzKurukaya I've updated the code you may check it and it's not necessary to use. I've used in whole app so i took lat long globally.